# Android Sending data to mysql using json

Tags: php, android, json

I want to send a string from `Android` to a `mysql` database using json. In a `.php` file I use `$_POST` to take values from Android. And in Android, I heard that it can be done through `AsyncTask`. Can anyone please tell how to do it using `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6525396/1405983)? Use this along with `AsyncTask` which MT8 suggest you.

Also refer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251732/1405983).

Answer (score -1):

First Search on Google: There are Many Question and Answer Same as Your Question:

#### On Google : [Click to Search](http://bit.ly/16bxv6m)

#### This will help to you : [How To Make HTTP POST Request To Server - Android Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)